# How to find b ( the most efficient way) in $ax^2+bxy+ cy^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics

I know the very basic way to find the b in this quadratic expression:
$$P(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+ cy^2$$
I can first evaluate $P(0,1)=c$.  Similarly, I can do $P(1,0)=a$ and then I can do $\frac{P(1,1)-P(1,-1)}{2}$ to find $b$.
This took **three steps**.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?
My Prof. gave a hint to use this fact:
$$P(tx_1,...,tx_n)= t^nP(x_1,...,x_n)$$

Comment: You can find $b$ if you know $P(1,1)$ and $P(-1,-1)$

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I have to disagree with @Henry.

$P(1,1)=a+b+c$ and $P(-1,-1)=a+b+c$ and you cannot do anything with that to find $b$ (unless you already know $a$ and $c$).

What you want to know is $P(1,1)=a+b+c$ and $P(1,-1)=a-b+c$

Then $P(1,1)-P(1,-1)=...$ will give you a way in to finding $b$.

Comment: @tiomi After finding $P(1,1)-P(1,-1)$, i think, we then have to divide by 2 in order to find b.

Comment: Correct. So you only need two observations or measurements from the $P$ function.